# convert amount from numeric to words in xcode

Tags: xcode

I need to convert the user enter amount into words.  For example, 1230.30 into one thousand two hundered and thirty rupees thirty paise.So,how to convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public  string NumberToText(int number) 
{ 
    if (number == 0) return "Zero"; 
    if (number == -2147483648) return "Minus Two Hundred and Fourteen Crore Seventy Four Lakh Eighty Three Thousand Six Hundred and Forty Eight"; 
    int[] num = new int[4]; 
    int first = 0; 
    int u, h, t; 
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); 
    if (number < 0) 
    { 
        sb.Append("Minus "); 
        number = -number; 
    } 
    string[] words0 = {"" ,"One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ", 
    "Five " ,"Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine "}; 
    string[] words1 = {"Ten ", "Eleven ", "Twelve ", "Thirteen ", "Fourteen ", 
    "Fifteen ","Sixteen ","Seventeen ","Eighteen ", "Nineteen "}; 
    string[] words2 = {"Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Forty ", "Fifty ", "Sixty ", 
    "Seventy ","Eighty ", "Ninety "}; 
    string[] words3 = {"Thousand ", "Lakh ","Crore "}; 
    num[0] = number % 1000; // units 
    num[1] = number / 1000; 
    num[2] = number / 100000; 
    num[1] = num[1] - 100 * num[2]; // thousands 
    num[3] = number / 10000000; // crores 
    num[2] = num[2] - 100 * num[3]; // lakhs 
    for(int i = 3; i > 0 ; i--) 
    { 
        if (num[i] != 0) 
        { 
            first = i; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    for(int i = first ; i >= 0 ; i--) 
    { 
        if (num[i] == 0) continue; 
        u = num[i] % 10; // ones 
        t = num[i] / 10; 
        h = num[i] / 100; // hundreds 
        t = t - 10 * h; // tens 
        if (h > 0) sb.Append(words0[h] + "Hundred "); 
        if (u > 0 || t > 0) 
        { 
            if (h > 0 || i == 0) sb.Append("and "); 
            if (t == 0) 
            sb.Append(words0[u]); 
            else if (t == 1) 
            sb.Append(words1[u]); 
            else 
            sb.Append(words2[t-2] + words0[u]); 
        } 
        if (i != 0) sb.Append(words3[i-1]); 
    } 
    return sb.ToString().TrimEnd(); 
}
```

Comment: 4 spaces do the trick. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks